# Can I give a class to a path drawn on a canvas with javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm randomly drawing little stars on a canvas with the beginPath() method like this:

```
function makeStars(){
  for(let i=0; i<100; i++){
    let startingX = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasWidth);
    let startingY = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasHeight);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startingX, startingY);
    ctx.lineTo(startingX-3,startingY+9.4);
    ctx.lineTo(startingX+4.5, startingY+3.5);
    ctx.lineTo(startingX-4.5, startingY+3.4);
    ctx.lineTo(startingX+3, startingY+9.4);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
```

Is it possible to give each path a class? Something like `ctx.classList.add('star');`? Ultimately, I was hoping to be able to animate them with CSS.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Looks like CSS is not the way to go. I think I'll just try to animate my stars with javaScript in a setInterval loop. Here's a codepen of what I'm working with. [Twinkling Stars Canvas](https://codepen.io/nitwit/pen/qLXOmg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CSS cannot animate or interact with canvas drawing.

But You can create a `Star` class which will provide OOP way of updating, rendering and animating the stars.

and then push all of the stars in an array and update/render them on animate loop.

https://codepen.io/anuraghazra/pen/WLLQJv

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: No. CSS doesn't act on elements drawn on a canvas.

Drawing to a canvas is like drawing directly to paper. You're using the 2D context to act on the pen. While you *could* figure out a way to read the CSS and perform the animations (by redrawing and redrawing the canvas), I would think that would be way more difficult than any other alternative.

If you're set on using CSS, one alternative is to use [`SVG`+`CSS`](https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/). The elements within the `SVG` can react to your `CSS`, much like `HTML` elements.

If you absolutely have to use a canvas, you could also draw the SVG to your canvas. [Convert the `SVG` to a Data URI](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/09-svg-data-uris/), then load that URI into an `Image` object, which you can then `putImage` onto the canvas. You would have to figure out how to draw each time the `SVG` updates, or poll for the new `SVG` information at an interval (like `requestAnimationFrame`).

Comment: If they already have an SVG image, they don't need the canvas, so your last paragraph is a little odd.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Oh, I agree. Which is why I prefaced it with the _need_ to use a `canvas`. The canvas may be involved in drawing other things, too. Sure, you could go the other way and insert elements into the `SVG`, like using `foreignObject` to directly inject the `canvas` but I erred on the side of the question looking to animate the stars drawn directly to the canvas.

Comment: Hmm ok, I think I understand. I don't actually have an SVG image, I"m just drawing directly on the canvas.

 I'm not set on using CSS, so maybe I'll just try to do the animations in javaScript. 

What if I just redraw the canvas on a setInterval(). Changing the size or opacity of my stars. Would that be a reasonable way to go about it?

Comment: @georgedum Yes, absolutely. It might even be worthwhile to think about how you could make a `Star` class, which can track its own RGBA, position, etc., and can draw itself to a given canvas. If you're not sure how to do the animation, look for "tweening" libraries. There are many available for JavaScript.